# vim - config for me with multiple users on same machine

Tags: vim

I'm editing files on a shared machine. How do I configure vim for me, while allowing other users their configuration (which may be 'unconfigured')?

(edit, should have noted this initially:) Unfortunately we all have to use the same login ID so config file in home directory isn't a solution for me. Is there an environment variable I could set manually after login to tell vim where to load "my" config?

Comment: Umm put settings into your home directory? (`~/.vim` and `~/.vimrc`) or do you not have separate users?

Comment: Are you editing as a different user? if so just put it in your user's home directory. if you're all editing as the same user, you've done something wrong with your life.

Comment: You can run `vim -u /path/to/your/vimrcfile` to use your own settings file.

Comment: You should make different logins per user like a non-insane person and fire your sysadmin

Answer (score 3):

Your configurations are in your `~/.vimrc` in your home folder. Your settings are therefore unique to your username. You should have no problem with others on the machine.

EDIT: Since you can't use a home folder (why again?), you can launch vim with a custom configuration script with the following:

```
vim -u custom.vimrc
```

If you have a `.bash_profile` or something similar, you can alias this to your own custom vim.

```
alias vime='vim -u custom.vimrc'
```

Comment: Thanks for the home directory suggestions. I should have noted that's not possible in this case. (Original post edited to include that.)

Comment: You can't use the `.bash_profile` thats also shared between all the users.

Comment: thanks - the -u option info was just what i needed (i'm too new here to be allowed to mark your answer as useful)